# C++ question on file formats and od

Tags: c++, file-format, octal

I have the following simple code:

```
ofstream output("test");
output << 'a';
```

When I do an octal dump of the file, I get this:

```
0000000 000141
0000001
```

I can see that 000141 (in base 8) is 8 bits wide and 0000001 is probably EOF.
What is the first byte of all 0's and why is it there? I know it is null is ascii
but what is its purpose?

Comment: I believe those numbers in the left-hand column are byte index numbers, not characters from your file (otherwise, why do they have eight digits instead of six?)

Comment: @James: Good catch.  The deeper mystery is why octal.

Comment: There won't be a specific EOF marker in a file, as that would require that no file have that marker inside it (the same reason you can't have `'\0'` in a C-style string).  The file length will be maintained independently.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with C++ (except the source code that shows we've got a file of length 1 with an 'a' in it), you probably should've tagged this linux or hexdump, because it looks to me like the output of the linux tool hd/hexdump using octal output.

See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) for more information.

EDIT: Ah, I missed the question title. So it's [od](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump#od_and_hexdump), the octal "brother" of hd.

The first column shows the file offsets (7 digits, hex), just like James said. If the file would be longer, it'd be more obvious.